# Having trouble using ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to implement ReactCSSTransitionGroup and followed the example on the React website. I am using React 0.14-rc1 and for some reason the ReactCSSTransitionGroup component does not seem to have any affect. I am not even getting any errors on the console. my code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import styles from './AddEventForm.css';
import withStyles from '../../../../../decorators/withStyles';
import Link from '../../../../../utils/Link';
import DateSelects from '../DateSelects';
import {StartDateSelect} from '../DateSelects';
import {EndDateSelect} from '../DateSelects';
import {EventTypeSelect} from '../DateSelects';
import ProfileStore from '../../../../../stores/ProfileStore';
import TimelineStore from '../../../../../stores/TimelineStore';
import TimelineDispatcher from '../../../../../dispatchers/TimelineDispatcher';
import TimelineActions from '../../../../../actions/TimelineActions';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';

let getProfileState = () => {
  return {
    profile: ProfileStore.getProfile()
  };
}

let getTimelineState = () => {
  return {
    timeline: TimelineStore.getEvents()
  };
}

class AddEventForm extends React.Component {

  _onChange() {
    this.setState(getTimelineState());
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.state.files = [];
    this.state.profile = getProfileState();
    this.state.timeline = getTimelineState();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    TimelineStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    TimelineStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange.bind(this));
  }

  onDrop(files) {
    console.log('Received files: ', files);
    this.setState({
      files: files
    });
  }

  render() {

    return(
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
            transitionEnterTimeout={500}
            transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
            transitionName="EventForm">
        <form onSubmit={ TimelineActions.createEvent.bind(this) } id="addTimelineEventForm" className="AddTimelineEvent">
          <a className="AddTimelineEventCloseButton" onClick={ TimelineActions.closeModal.bind(this) }>
            <i className="fa fa-times"></i>
          </a>
          <h3>Add Event</h3>
          <div className="AddEventTitle TimelineFormField">
            <input ref="event_title"
            className="TimelineInput" placeholder="Title" />
          </div>
          <div className="AddEventPlace TimelineFormField">
            <input ref="event_place"
            className="TimelineInput" placeholder="Place" />
          </div>
          <div className="AddEventLocation TimelineFormField">
            <input ref="event_location"
            className="TimelineInput" placeholder="Location" />
          </div>
          <div className="AddEventDescription TimelineFormField">
            <textarea ref="event_description"
            rows="2" className="TimelineInput" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
          </div>
          <StartDateSelect />
          <EndDateSelect />
          <EventTypeSelect />
          <div className="AddEventMedia TimelineFormField">
            <Dropzone className="Dropzone" activeClassName="DropzoneActive" ref="dropzone" multiple={true} disableClick={false} onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>
              <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
              {this.state.files.length > 0 ? 
              <div>
                <div>{this.state.files.map((file) => 
                  <div className="DropzoneUploadedImageContainer">
                    <img className="DropzoneUploadedImage" key={file.preview} src={file.preview} />
                    <br className="clear" />
                  </div> )}
                </div>
                <p className="DropzoneFileCount">{this.state.files.length} files</p>
              </div> : null}
            </Dropzone>
            <p className="AddTimelineEventNote">Note: Images only, maximum 4 images and maximum file size is 2 MB</p>
            <button type="submit" form="addTimelineEventForm" className="SaveEventButton btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <a onClick={ TimelineActions.closeModal.bind(this) } className="SaveEventButton btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default AddEventForm;
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes scaleUp {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(0.2);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleDown {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:scale(1);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(0);
  }
}

.EventForm-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
}

.EventForm-appear {
  opacity: 0.01;
  transition: scaleUp .5s ease-in;
}

.EventForm-enter.EventForm-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform:scale(1);
}

.EventForm-leave {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: scaleDown .5s ease-in;
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: When you inspect your form element in your browser, which classnames does it have? EventForm? EventForm-appear?

Comment: Just the 'AddTimelineEvent' class. It does not seem to add the classnames from the CSSTransitionGroup at all. I have never used the component so not sure if everything is as it should be.

Comment: React docs say that each child of CSStransitiongroup should have have a `key=...` maybe that helps?

Comment: added the key as well but still no change

Answer (score 2):

The [official react docs on CSS transitions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animate-initial-mounting) explain that when initially mounted, components inside transition group do not get animated.

`-enter` and `enter-active` classes are only applied when item is added after an update. Either trough state change, or through re-rendering of parent component.

If you want to animate on *initial* mounting, you should add `transitionAppear={true}` to your ReactCSSTransitionGroup component. The corresponding css classes are `AddTimeLineEvent-appear` and `AddTimeLineEvent-appear-active`.

Hope this fixes it.

BTW: if you only want to have an animation on initial mounting, you can add a function on componentDidMount():

```
this.refs.getDOMNode('myRef').classList.add("active");
```

and add `ref="myRef"` to your form to set off the animation. Then you do not need react CSS transitions.

Comment: I got the following warning on the console and nothing happens still: warning.js:45 Warning: Failed propType: transitionAppearTimeout wasn't supplied to ReactCSSTransitionGroup: this can cause unreliable animations and won't be supported in a future version of React. See https://fb.me/react-animation-transition-group-timeout for more information. Check the render method of `AddEventForm`.

Comment: The message suggest you also added `transitionAppearTimeOut`. This is where you get the error. Remove the timeouts. Probably better to handle timeouts with css anyway.

Comment: It is giving out the error for all three of these if I remove the timeouts: transitionAppearTimeout, transitionEnterTimeout, transitionLeaveTimeout . It doesnt throw the error if I include the timeouts but it doesnt work either.

Comment: Probably error isn't presented if you *exclude* the timeouts. I think it should work then. Can you share your actual latest code? Or otherwise try alternative option.

Comment: I have tried your solution for adding the classes on  componentDidMount() and the class does get added but for some reason the transition still does not seem to work

Comment: Make sure the class on initial mount (part of render function) is different than class after componentDidMount. If your browser developer mode also shows class change, then there is some issue with your css transition.